# Can you identify this scale? Cant find it in the Mela chart. Is it Persian, Arabic? C Db Eb Fb G Ab B C

Tags: modal

Can you identify this scale? Cant find it in the Mela chart. Is it Persian, Arabic? C Db Eb Fb G Ab B C

Comment: Just saying: Properly identifying a scale is not hard, in this case it would be 121313. Assigning a name to something like this is quite arbitrary, and thus of limited use.

Answer (score 1):

Ianring.com calls this scale "[Ionocrian](https://ianring.com/musictheory/scales/2459)". It is also discussed, with different details described, [at stanleyjordan.com](https://www.stanleyjordan.com/MusicTheory/ChromaticSystem/chordTypesMainPages/013478B.html).

To the best of my understanding the name was assigned by [William Zeitler](http://www.allthescales.org/).

scales-chords.com [doesn't list it](https://www.scales-chords.com/fscale_res_en.php?rn1=C&rn2=C%23%2FDb&rn3=D%23%2FEb&rn4=E&rn5=G&rn6=G%23%2FAb&rn7=B&rn8=C&rn9=&normal=1&greek=1&greekalt=1&other=1&etnic=1&c1=&t1=&c2=&t2=&c3=&t3=).

The scale exists as a "hypothetical" scale, with the name assigned for convenience, but it's not used in any of the major musical systems.